# Remove model from Devise urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How do I remove the model name from Devise urls?

Ie

```
users/sign_in -> /sign_in
users/sign_out -> /sign_out
users/registration/sign_up -> /sign_up
users/registration/edit -> /edit
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that in this project I run Rails 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered in the devise README (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise):

> Devise also ships with default routes.
>   If you need to customize them, you
>   should probably be able to do it
>   through the devise_for method. It
>   accepts several options like
>   :class_name, :path_prefix and so on,
>   including the possibility to change
>   path names for I18n:

```
  devise_for :users, :path => "usuarios", :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :password => 'secret', :confirmation => 'verification', :unlock => 'unblock', :registration => 'register', :sign_up => 'cmon_let_me_in' }
```

> Be sure to check
>   devise_for documentation for details.
>
> If you have the need for more deep
>   customization, for instance to also
>   allow "/sign_in" besides
>   "/users/sign_in", all you need to do
>   is to create your routes normally and
>   wrap them in a devise_scope block in
>   the router:

```
  devise_scope :user do
     get "sign_in", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
  end
```

> This way
>   you tell devise to use the scope :user
>   when "/sign_in" is accessed. Notice
>   devise_scope is also aliased as as and
>   you can also give a block to
>   devise_for, resulting in the same
>   behavior:

```
   devise_for :users do
     get "sign_in", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
   end
```

> Feel free
>   to choose the one you prefer!

(Maybe this wasn't in the README when this question was originally posed.)

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this manually is Rails 3 would be:

```
match 'sign_in' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :sign_in
match 'sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :sign_out
```